# Sorting Data and merging

Tags: r, dataset, mergesort, data-analysis

```
v1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
v2<-c("Jan","Jan","Jan","Feb","Feb","Jan","Jan","Feb","Jan","Jan","Feb","Feb","Feb","Feb","Feb")
v3<-c("A1","E1","F1","B1","A1","E1","B1","C1","B1","D1","E1","A1","B1","C1","F1")
dt <- data.table(emp_id=v1,month=v2,work=v3)
```

[image]

I want to convert it into a dataframe/datatable such every `work` done by one `emp_id` is arranged **sequentially** as in the `dt` and is stored in a vector which is further stored in a column as shown below.

[image]

I have used

```
dt1 <- dt[, .(work = list(work)), emp_id]
temp<-as.vector(dt1$work[3])
length(temp)
```

But the result is **showing 1**. I want the sorting in such a way that it should show the **result 3** *as there are 3 elements in second row - E1,B1,C1* .

Answer (score 0):

We can place it in a `list` of `vector`s grouped by 'emp_id'

```
dt1 <- dt[, .(work = list(work)), emp_id]
dt1
#   emp_id               work
#1:      1     A1,E1,F1,B1,A1
#2:      2           E1,B1,C1
#3:      3 B1,D1,E1,A1,B1,C1,

dt1$work
[[1]]
#[1] "A1" "E1" "F1" "B1" "A1"

#[[2]]
#[1] "E1" "B1" "C1"

#[[3]]
#[1] "B1" "D1" "E1" "A1" "B1" "C1" "F1"
```

---

Or use `split` in to a named `list` of `vector`s

```
split(dt$work, dt$emp_id)
```

Comment: But dt$work is not a vector? `vv<-as.vector(dt1$work[2])` and 
`length(vv)` then it is showing output as 1 instead of 3 i.e. (E1, B1, C1)

Comment: @sid It is a `list` of `vector`s.  You need to `is.vector(dt1$work[[2]])`